AutoMapper 13 is not compatible with .NET 6.0 even though it is compatible with .NET 6.0
I didn't know when this problem starts to occur, but a few weeks back the AutoMapper package that I download from NuGet works fine, but now, when I try to install Automapper 13.0.1 with always prompt the error

Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error (active)  NU1202  Package AutoMapper 13.0.1 is not compatible with net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0). Package AutoMapper 13.0.1 does not support any target frameworks.

In the document i read by NuGet:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/automapper/
It is completely compatible with .NET 6.0, my project is definitely using .NET 6.0. I have been trying to resolve the issue but there's so little information about it on google, the error occur across all .NET project in my computer
This is one of my project config for reference
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="13.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="6.0.32" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.32" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData" Version="8.2.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="6.0.32">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.32" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.6.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger" Version="6.6.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen" Version="6.6.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI" Version="6.6.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>


Clearly this has nothing to to with AM, but with VS. This should happen woth any package targeting .Net 6.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio and the problem still occurs, and it only happens to AutoMapper specifically, seems like it does not work with .NET 8.0 too

Thousands of people use AM on different frameworks, so the problem must be on your end. You can also try the MyGet build.
